# Is there an adapter that exists to split an ethernet cable into 2 cables, allowing simultaneous use?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, cable, splitter

The ethernet splitter adapters I find on Amazon all specify that you can use only one device at a time. I want to split one ethernet cable into two ethernet cables and be able to use the connexion on both devices at the same time.

```
                                  ----Eth cable 2-----> Device
Router ---Eth cable 1---> Adapter
                                  ----Eth cable 3-----> Device
```

The reason I want to do this, is because the router is far from the 2 devices and I much prefer passing only 1 cable (instead of 2) from one room to the other.

Is this possible?

**EDIT 1**

```
       --Eth cable-->
Router               Sharing Kit --> Coupler --> --Eth cable--> Coupler --> Sharing Kit -> my two devices
       --Eth cable-->
```

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the answer. Is there no way to achieve what I want to achieve? Can I pass 2 very short cables from the router to an adapter, then one cable from the adapter to another adapter in the other room, split back to two cables? Cheers!

Comment: Ethernet joiner/splitter adapters were possible for 100Mbit Ethernet only as this mode used only 4 of the 8 connections of a CAT5 cable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there an adapter that exists to split an ethernet cable into 2 cables, allowing simultaneous use?

Yes, it is called a (Ethernet) switch.
Use one port to connect to the router in the other room.
Use two other ports for each device in this remote room.

```
                         Switch 
                         | | |
                         | | +--------Eth cable 3-----> Device
Router ---Eth cable 1----+ |
                           +----------Eth cable 2-----> Device
```

Note that a switch will require electrical power, e.g. a wall wart.

---

Apparently your use of the word *"split"* has confused some responders, as that term is often associated with an Ethernet wiring hack.
With a switch the devices in the remote room are *sharing* the single cable to the router.
In networking terminology this is known as cascading or daisy-chaining.
See [Cascading your Switch to Another Switch](https://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=133007).
(If your router has more than one downstream port, then it has a integrated switch.)

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try that. Just bought [NETGEAR 8-Port Gigabit Ethernet Unmanaged Switch (GS308) - Desktop, Sturdy Metal Fanless Housing](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07PFYM5MZ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Comment: Yes, that *"adapter"* will achieve what you described.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a single cable and use an an [ethernet cable sharing kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N0RRPX6). See the connection diagram:

[image]

You still need to have two switch ports on one side, that will be sent to the other side, over a single cable, as two ports.

Or a switch. That's, I think, the best way to solve it.

Comment: I don't get it. Would I need to pass 2 small cables from my router to a sharing kit, then the sharing kit to a rj45 coupler, then a long cable from the rj45 coupler to another rj45 coupler in the other room, then a sharing kit connected to this second rj45 coupler, then both devices connected to the second sharing kit?

Comment: See my edit please

Comment: Check the diagram at the bottom. It's just one cable you'd be passing.